# datasource error while packaging to jar a deskctop spring boot project

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, build, jar

I have a deskctop spring boot project that when I clean and build it in the IDE i have some Errors but it works and is BUILD SUCCESS.

Errors:

```
2021-10-20 13:21:49.588  WARN 20976 --- [   scheduling-1] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyConnection   : HikariPool-1 - Connection oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection@4cc36c19 marked as broken because of SQLSTATE(08006), ErrorCode(17002)

java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: Error de E/S: Socket read interrupted
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.executeForDescribe(T4CPreparedStatement.java:941) ~[ojdbc8-21.1.0.0.jar:21.1.0.0.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.prepareDefineBufferAndExecute(OracleStatement.java:1158) ~[ojdbc8-21.1.0.0.jar:21.1.0.0.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.executeMaybeDescribe(OracleStatement.java:1093) ~[ojdbc8-21.1.0.0.jar:21.1.0.0.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.executeSQLSelect(OracleStatement.java:1402) ~[ojdbc8-21.1.0.0.jar:21.1.0.0.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1285) ~[ojdbc8-21.1.0.0.jar:21.1.0.0.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3735) ~[ojdbc8-21.1.0.0.jar:21.1.0.0.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeQuery(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3847) ~[ojdbc8-21.1.0.0.jar:21.1.0.0.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.executeQuery(OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.java:1098) ~[ojdbc8-21.1.0.0.jar:21.1.0.0.0]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyPreparedStatement.executeQuery(ProxyPreparedStatement.java:52) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyPreparedStatement.executeQuery(HikariProxyPreparedStatement.java) [HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:57) [hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getResultSet(Loader.java:2297) [hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:2050) [hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:2012) [hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:948) [hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:349) [hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2843) [hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2825) [hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2657) [hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2652) [hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:506) [hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:400) [hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:219) [hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1414) [hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.doList(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1636) [hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.list(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1604) [hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.getSingleResult(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1652) [hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.count(SimpleJpaRepository.java:574) [spring-data-jpa-2.5.2.jar:2.5.2]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_271]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_271]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_271]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_271]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker$RepositoryFragmentMethodInvoker.lambda$new$0(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:289) [spring-data-commons-2.5.2.jar:2.5.2]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.doInvoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:137) ~[spring-data-commons-2.5.2.jar:2.5.2]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.invoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:121) ~[spring-data-commons-2.5.2.jar:2.5.2]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition$RepositoryFragments.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:529) ~[spring-data-commons-2.5.2.jar:2.5.2]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:285) ~[spring-data-commons-2.5.2.jar:2.5.2]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$ImplementationMethodExecutionInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:599) ~[spring-data-commons-2.5.2.jar:2.5.2]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:163) ~[spring-data-commons-2.5.2.jar:2.5.2]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:138) ~[spring-data-commons-2.5.2.jar:2.5.2]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:123) ~[spring-tx-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:388) ~[spring-tx-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:119) ~[spring-tx-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:137) ~[spring-tx-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:174) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.5.2.jar:2.5.2]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:97) ~[spring-aop-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:215) ~[spring-aop-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy102.count(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at co.XXXXXXXX.XXXXXXXX.SXXXXXXX..count(XXXXXXXXXXX.java:34) ~[classes/:na]
    at co.XXXXX.X.Core.PXXXXrocesoPrincipal.tareaProgramada(XXXXXXXXX.java:75) ~[classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_271]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_271]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_271]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_271]
    at org.springframework.scheduling.support.ScheduledMethodRunnable.run(ScheduledMethodRunnable.java:84) ~[spring-context-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:54) ~[spring-context-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) ~[na:1.8.0_271]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:308) ~[na:1.8.0_271]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180) ~[na:1.8.0_271]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:294) ~[na:1.8.0_271]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) ~[na:1.8.0_271]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) ~[na:1.8.0_271]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) ~[na:1.8.0_271]
Caused by: java.io.InterruptedIOException: Socket read interrupted
    at oracle.net.nt.TimeoutSocketChannel.handleInterrupt(TimeoutSocketChannel.java:549) ~[ojdbc8-21.1.0.0.jar:21.1.0.0.0]
    at oracle.net.nt.TimeoutSocketChannel.read(TimeoutSocketChannel.java:420) ~[ojdbc8-21.1.0.0.jar:21.1.0.0.0]
    at oracle.net.ns.NSProtocolNIO.doSocketRead(NSProtocolNIO.java:1119) ~[ojdbc8-21.1.0.0.jar:21.1.0.0.0]
    at oracle.net.ns.NIOPacket.readHeader(NIOPacket.java:267) ~[ojdbc8-21.1.0.0.jar:21.1.0.0.0]
    at oracle.net.ns.NIOPacket.readPacketFromSocketChannel(NIOPacket.java:199) ~[ojdbc8-21.1.0.0.jar:21.1.0.0.0]
    at oracle.net.ns.NIOPacket.readFromSocketChannel(NIOPacket.java:141) ~[ojdbc8-21.1.0.0.jar:21.1.0.0.0]
    at oracle.net.ns.NIOPacket.readFromSocketChannel(NIOPacket.java:114) ~[ojdbc8-21.1.0.0.jar:21.1.0.0.0]
    at oracle.net.ns.NIONSDataChannel.readDataFromSocketChannel(NIONSDataChannel.java:98) ~[ojdbc8-21.1.0.0.jar:21.1.0.0.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CMAREngineNIO.prepareForUnmarshall(T4CMAREngineNIO.java:834) ~[ojdbc8-21.1.0.0.jar:21.1.0.0.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CMAREngineNIO.unmarshalUB1(T4CMAREngineNIO.java:487) ~[ojdbc8-21.1.0.0.jar:21.1.0.0.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:577) ~[ojdbc8-21.1.0.0.jar:21.1.0.0.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:291) ~[ojdbc8-21.1.0.0.jar:21.1.0.0.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.doOALL(T4C8Oall.java:492) ~[ojdbc8-21.1.0.0.jar:21.1.0.0.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.doOall8(T4CPreparedStatement.java:148) ~[ojdbc8-21.1.0.0.jar:21.1.0.0.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.executeForDescribe(T4CPreparedStatement.java:928) ~[ojdbc8-21.1.0.0.jar:21.1.0.0.0]
    ... 68 common frames omitted

2021-10-20 13:21:49.589  WARN 20976 --- [   scheduling-1] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 17002, SQLState: 08006
2021-10-20 13:21:49.590 ERROR 20976 --- [   scheduling-1] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : Error de E/S: Socket read interrupted
2021-10-20 13:21:49.594 ERROR 20976 --- [   scheduling-1] o.s.t.i.TransactionInterceptor           : Application exception overridden by rollback exception

.
.
.
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationNotAllowedException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSourceScriptDatabaseInitializer': Singleton bean creation not allowed while singletons of this factory are in destruction (Do not request a bean from a BeanFactory in a destroy method implementation!)
2021-10-20 13:21:50.381  INFO 20976 --- [ionShutdownHook] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown completed.

.
.
.
Results:

Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0
.
.
------------------------------------------------------------------------
BUILD SUCCESS
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Total time:  44.029 s
Finished at: 2021-10-20T13:21:53-05:00
------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Even with those mistakes the project works correctly.

But now I have to package it as a .jar (mvn package) but it throw to me some errors:

```
2021-10-20 12:33:54.726  WARN 22324 --- [           main] o.s.w.c.s.GenericWebApplicationContext   : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSourceScriptDatabaseInitializer' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/sql/init/DataSourceInitializationConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'dataSourceScriptDatabaseInitializer' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceConfiguration$Hikari.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties$DataSourceBeanCreationException: Failed to determine a suitable driver class
2021-10-20 12:33:54.740  INFO 22324 --- [           main] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener :

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2021-10-20 12:33:54.768 ERROR 22324 --- [           main] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   :

***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Failed to configure a DataSource: 'url' attribute is not specified and no embedded datasource could be configured.

Reason: Failed to determine a suitable driver class
.
.
.
2021-10-20 12:33:54.778 ERROR 22324 --- [           main] o.s.test.context.TestContextManager      : Caught exception while allowing TestExecutionListener [org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener@5524cca1] to prepare test instance [co.xxxxxxx.xxxxxxx.xxxxxxApplicationTests@342726f1]

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
        at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:132) ~[spring-test-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
        at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:124) ~[spring-test-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
        at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.setUpRequestContextIfNecessary(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:190) ~[spring-test-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
        at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:132) ~[spring-test-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
        at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:248) ~[spring-test-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit.jupiter.SpringExtension.postProcessTestInstance(SpringExtension.java:138) [spring-test-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestInstancePostProcessors$6(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:350) [junit-jupiter-engine-5.7.2.jar:5.7.2]
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.executeAndMaskThrowable(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:355) [junit-jupiter-engine-5.7.2.jar:5.7.2]
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestInstancePostProcessors$7(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:350) [junit-jupiter-engine-5.7.2.jar:5.7.2]
        at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:193) ~[na:1.8.0_271]
        at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:175) ~[na:1.8.0_271]
        at java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1384) ~[na:1.8.0_271]
        at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:482) ~[na:1.8.0_271]
        at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:472) ~[na:1.8.0_271]
        at java.util.stream.StreamSpliterators$WrappingSpliterator.forEachRemaining(StreamSpliterators.java:312) ~[na:1.8.0_271]
        at java.util.stream.Streams$ConcatSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Streams.java:743) ~[na:1.8.0_271]
        at java.util.stream.Streams$ConcatSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Streams.java:742) ~[na:1.8.0_271]
        at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$Head.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:580) ~[na:1.8.0_271]
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.invokeTestInstancePostProcessors(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:349) [junit-jupiter-engine-5.7.2.jar:5.7.2]
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$instantiateAndPostProcessTestInstance$4(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:270) [junit-jupiter-engine-5.7.2.jar:5.7.2]
.
.
.
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_271]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_271]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_271]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_271]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154) ~[spring-beans-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
        ... 102 common frames omitted

[ERROR] Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 3.285 s <<< FAILURE! - in co.X.X.XXXXXXApplicationTests
[ERROR] contextLoads  Time elapsed: 0.001 s  <<< ERROR!
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSourceScriptDatabaseInitializer' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/sql/init/DataSourceInitializationConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'dataSourceScriptDatabaseInitializer' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceConfiguration$Hikari.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties$DataSourceBeanCreationException: Failed to determine a suitable driver class
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceConfiguration$Hikari.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties$DataSourceBeanCreationException: Failed to determine a suitable driver class
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties$DataSourceBeanCreationException: Failed to determine a suitable driver class
Caused by: org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties$DataSourceBeanCreationException: Failed to determine a suitable driver class


[INFO]
[INFO] Results:
[INFO]
[ERROR] Errors:
[ERROR]   xxxxxxxApplicationTests.contextLoads » IllegalState Failed to load Application...
[INFO]
[ERROR] Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0
[INFO]

[INFO] BUILD FAILURE

[INFO] Total time:  8.726 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2021-10-20T12:33:56-05:00

[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.22.2:test (default-test) on project DesplegableXXXXX: There are test failures.
[ERROR]
```

I don´t know if are errors of some about the test (I didn´t use it) or some about the same errors that appear when I build the project like the firt block I show up.

And my application.properties:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@//xxxxxxx:xxxx/dedok
spring.datasource.username=ERD
spring.datasource.password=erd_prueba
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver

spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL=debug
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle12cDialect
```

Do you know what can be the error I have here? please I will apresiate your help.

I add my pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.2</version>
        <relativePath/> 
    </parent>
    <groupId>co.xxxx</groupId>
    <artifactId>projectName</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <name>projectName</name>
    <description>radicados cordis sdqs</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.oracle.database.jdbc</groupId>
            <artifactId>ojdbc8</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
                </dependency>
     <dependency>
      <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
      <artifactId>org.eclipse.persistence.core</artifactId>
      <version>2.5.2</version>
     </dependency>
     <dependency>
      <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
      <artifactId>org.eclipse.persistence.asm</artifactId>
      <version>2.5.2</version>
     </dependency>
     <dependency>
      <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
      <artifactId>org.eclipse.persistence.antlr</artifactId>
      <version>2.5.2</version>
     </dependency>
     <dependency>
      <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
      <artifactId>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa</artifactId>
      <version>2.5.2</version>
     </dependency>
     <dependency>
      <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
      <artifactId>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.jpql</artifactId>
      <version>2.5.2</version>
     </dependency>
     <dependency>
      <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
      <artifactId>javax.persistence</artifactId>
      <version>2.1.0</version>
     </dependency>
     <dependency>
      <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
      <artifactId>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.modelgen.processor</artifactId>
      <version>2.5.2</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
     </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
            <artifactId>bcprov-jdk15on</artifactId>
            <version>1.67</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.samba.jcifs</groupId>
            <artifactId>jcifs</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
            <artifactId>bcmail-jdk15on</artifactId>
            <version>1.47</version>
        </dependency>
         <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.mail</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.mail</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.5</version>
        </dependency>
     <dependency>
      <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
      <version>2.4</version>
      <type>jar</type>
     </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
          <resources>
                <resource>
                      <targetPath>META-INF</targetPath>
                      <directory>src</directory>
                      <includes>
                            <include>jax-ws-catalog.xml</include>
                            <include>wsdl/**</include>
                      </includes>
                </resource>
                <resource>
                      <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                </resource>
          </resources>
          <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                </plugin>
                  <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.jvnet.jax-ws-commons</groupId>
                        <artifactId>jaxws-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>2.3</version>
                        <executions>
                              <execution>
                                    <goals>
                                          <goal>wsimport</goal>
                                    </goals>
                                    <configuration>
                                          <wsdlFiles>
                                                <wsdlFile>xxxxxxxx.wsdl</wsdlFile>
                                          </wsdlFiles>
                                          <packageName></packageName>
                                          <vmArgs>
                                                <vmArg>-Djavax.xml.accessExternalSchema=all</vmArg>
                                          </vmArgs>
<wsdlLocation>https://xxxxxx?wsdl</wsdlLocation>
                                          <staleFile>${project.build.directory}/jaxws/stale/xxxxxxxx.stale</staleFile>
                                    </configuration>
                                    <id>wsimport-generate-xxxxxxxxxxx</id>
                                    <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                              </execution>
                        </executions>
                        <dependencies>
                              <dependency>
                                    <groupId>javax.xml</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>webservices-api</artifactId>
                                    <version>2.0</version>
                              </dependency>
                        </dependencies>
                        <configuration>
                              <sourceDestDir>${project.build.directory}/generated-sources/jaxws-wsimport</sourceDestDir>
                              <xnocompile>true</xnocompile>
                              <verbose>true</verbose>
                              <extension>true</extension>
                              <catalog>${basedir}/src/jax-ws-catalog.xml</catalog>
                        </configuration>
                  </plugin>
            </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: Please provide your .pom file

Comment: @RomanKhomyshynets Now is added please take a look.

Comment: Try to change the scope of org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.modelgen.processor dependency from provided to default. Also provide the information how exactly are you running your packaged app. Which command you call and whether you use some application container

Comment: @RomanKhomyshynets tha same error:   
 WARN 272 -[   scheduling-1] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyConnection   : HikariPool-1 - Connection oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection@6edcad64 marked as broken because of SQLSTATE(08006), ErrorCode(17002)

java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: Error de E/S: Socket read interrupted
 at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.doRollback(T4CConnection.java:1670) ~[ojdbc8-21.1.0.0.jar:21.1.0.0.0]